# Ubuntu 16.04 HWE on Intel NUC 10?

Tags: drivers, kernel, graphics

I want to install Ubuntu on an Intel NUC 10 (specifically a NUC10i3FNK). For compatibility reasons, it *must* be Ubuntu 16.04.

First I attempted 16.04.6 because I had it lying as an image, but it did not support the Ethernet card.

If I install the latest point release, 16.04.7, and install all the upgrades, the Ethernet is duly detected - but the graphics card and the wifi are not.

While we could do without the Wifi, the graphics card absolutely must work.

I've tried a lot of things - like installing a newer mainline kernel (not possible because of dependency issues) or compiling a newer version of the graphics driver (failed because of the version of `meson` available in 16.04).

Do anyone have a tip, or possibly a solution? Unfortunately, using 18.04 or 20.04, which both support this computer without any issues is not an option at this time.

Comment: OK I have to ask why is it not an option at this time?

Comment: Typically newer hardware requires the newer versions of Ubuntu, so it has the newer kernel, drivers & other support software. Trying to use an older version leads to many other issues as you have found.

Comment: @David There's a custom installation that's on 16.04, and there's a port to 20.04, but the port is not production ready so we can't give it to the customer.

Comment: @oldfred Indeed! Right now it looks like the solution is to speed up the 20.04 port instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, I've concluded that the correct answer to this is: You shouldn't.

Keeping old systems alive with newer kernels is too huge an effort with such a time gap as there is between 16.04 and 20.04, and as a single developer or user you simply don't have the resources e.g. of the Ubuntu HWE project.